# Как убрать обратный слэш?

Tags: php

В результате выборки из базы получается стока [\"07.08.2018 02:00 -- 21.08.2018 06:00\"] Как убрать слэши? stripcslashes() не помогает

$arrResponse["text_cont_lead"] =  str_replace(array('\'), '', $id_amo22["text_cont_lead"]);
$arrResponse["is_active"] = $id_amo22["is_active"];
echo json_encode($arrResponse);

Может json_encode добавляет?

Comment: `str_replace('\\', '', $text)` - ?

Comment: `json_encode` - будет добавлять `\\` это нормально, после декодирования формата, они пропадут.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо, оформите как ответ. А проблем в браузере не будет?

Comment: Всё зависит от того, где, как и зачем вы всё это используете

Comment: json.parse принимает, Вроде проблем нет, но а в дальнейшем? Кроссбраузерность там ...

Answer (score 3):

`json_encode` - будет добавлять \ это нормально, после декодирования формата, они пропадут.

`json.parse` - нормально тоже отреагирует и удалить эти знаки, не волнуйтесь :)

`Кроссбраузерность там...`. `JSON` - это стандарт, у него в стандарте прописано экранизация двойных кавычек, собсна для декодирования их надо удалять. Декодирование выполняет не браузер а `JS`, так что не волнуйтесь :).